# Python super().__init__() TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im given some undocumented  code that runs well on Windows running Python 3, however after testing Im moving this Python do Ubuntu running Python 2.7.12.

I cant change Python version on the server because others are using it & may break their code.

The Python class that is having the error is:

```
import logging

    # device is a test class to handle replay functions
    class Device:
        intermittent = False
        loop = False


        def __init__(self, name, mac, description, srcFile, real):
            super().__init__()
            self.name = name
            self.MAC = mac
            self.description = description
            self.srcFile = srcFile
            self.running = False
            self.real = real

        def to_dictionary(self):
            data = {'name': self.name,
                    'mac': self.MAC,
                    'description': self.description,
                    'active': self.running,
                    'real': self.real}
            return data

        def start(self):
            logging.debug("starting " + self.name)
            self.running = True

        def resume(self):
            logging.debug("resuming " + self.name)
            self.running = True

        def stop(self):
            logging.debug("stopping " + self.name)
            self.running = False
```

I understand that Python 3 object oriented syntax is different than 2.7, how can I alter  this class to work with Python 2.7?

Thanks

Comment: "I cant change Python version on the server because others are using it & may break their code." That isn't a problem. You can install Python 3 without touching the existing Python 2. You will just run your script with the `python3` command, and they will continue running their scripts with the `python` command, and everything will work. That's a lot simpler than porting code from 3.x to 2.x without knowing the differences between the two.

Comment: "I cant change Python version on the server because others are using it & may break their code." - you can have your own Python 3 without messing with other users' Python 2.

Comment: Or, even better, you can use virtual environments, so each user—or even each program—can use whichever Python they want.

Comment: If you really do want to backport code without actually learning Python 2, you'd do a lot better to use [`3to2`](https://pypi.org/project/3to2/) or [`futurize`](https://pypi.org/project/future/) instead of running it, seeing if you get an error, posting a StackOverflow question, and repeating until it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zero-argument invocation of `super` is a new feature of Python 3.  If you want to write cross-compatible code, you can't use it.  See [PEP 3135 -- New Super](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/) for details about that.

> How can I alter this class to work with Python 2.7?

Firstly, the line `class Device:` should be changed to inherit `object`, so that you have a [new-style class](https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/).

Optionally, add `from future import unicode_literals` to the start of the module. Since you use string additions in the logging calls, you might need that if you deal with textual data in a `Device`'s attributes.  However, a better way to deal with that is arguably to use %-format strings in the log calls, for example:

```
logging.debug("starting %s", self.name)
```

Finally, the line

```
super().__init__()
```

could be changed to

```
super(Device, self).__init__()
```

All other things being equal, your code looks cross-compat now.

Though, I'm wondering why you use `super` at all here, it doesn't seem needed.

Comment: You're assuming that the `Device` constructor is called with `unicode` rather than `str` here? That's certainly possible, but it seems just as possible that they're, say, UTF-8 strings (which in 3.x automatically got decoded to `str` using the default UTF-8 encoding, but in 2.7 they get left as `str`, which you then try to `%s` into a unicode format string, which implicitly decodes them as ASCII).

Comment: @abarnert  A unicode exception within log formatting is caught, and also logged, contrast with a unicode exception in string addition which just blows up the stack. Since the code allegedly "runs well" on Python 3, I guess we can assume the `self.name` attribute is a `str`, but I would still recommend to %-template the log call regardless.  In the weird circumstance that both bytes and text need to be handled, you could use %r instead of %s.

Comment: I don't think you can assume that it's text. There are plenty of libraries—even much of the stdlib—that will give you "whatever `str` is" (text in 3.x but bytes in 2.x), rather than "text" (`str` in 3.x but `unicode` in 2.x).